# Upgrading to .NET 6.0 issue with timer

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

NET Framework 4.7.2 project to .NET 6.0 after successful upgrading I have rebuild and published project and installed in my system
I have created a logfile and used threading timer after few seconds it writes to log when service start once service stop the timer also stops in .NET Framework but after porting
After stopping the service the service will get Stop but timer not getting stopped it continues writing to logfile
Even I have used stop timer method that also not working
Please any help to this how to stop timer

Comment: Can you please share the reproducer?

Comment: U mean Screenshot?

Comment: No, I mean text code. Do not post code as images.

Comment: Im using system.threading.timer in my Onstart methode in a window service

Comment: protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart."); TTimer= new system.threading.Timer Callback(Ontimer),null,0,1000*2)
}public void OnTimer(object state)
{
    // TODO: Insert monitoring activities here.
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Monitoring the System", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);
}

Comment: When my service start every 2 interval it write to eventlog when I stop service it should stop timer also before porting it's working fine in .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer                                                                                                                       used this link for creating window service instead system.timer I used system.threading.timer

Comment: Any suggestions

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved by own
2 version of same version doesn't allow in same machine and once we create a service for .net6.0 after porting we need to restart system and again need to start service so it will work fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).